# Как сравнить две таблицы по артикулу?

Tags: excel, сравнение, google-spreadsheet, таблицы

Имеются две гугл таблицы, с разным количеством строк и разной сортировкой в каждой таблице есть столбец "Артикул". Нужно извлечь только те строки которые совпали по Артикулу и представить в таком виде для сравнения цены: 
[image: Пример конечного результата]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первой таблице в D3 и протянуть ниже:

```
  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3;$F$3:$H;3;);)
```

Подтянутся цены из второй таблицы.

Дальше - фильтр по значениям >0, копирование видимых в отдельный диапазон